# SWF file can't read json

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

I have created flash application and can read data from server. I have finished my app and it is working well when I run from flash (fla file). But when it is exported to SWF file, it can't read data from server. I use preloader and it is still 0%. I use JSON for this app as data from server.

What I did until now:

- Set target as flash player 11.2.
- Publish as .exe and it is working well (but I need SWF file).
- Put application/json on JSON file.

Anyone had this problem too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place a [`crossdomain.xml`](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) file on the root of the server that the data is being requested from. There are some [examples and guidelines here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/cross-domain-xml-for-streaming.html).

Here's one of the least restrictive implementations:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```